# Join and merge the two JSon files and alter the field name in the output json

Tags: python, json

I have two Json files with one common key with "Key" field in JSON1 and "ID_NO" field in JSON2 and i need to join the two files based on the common key and alter one of the field name in python.

I am trying to do this without using dataframes. Thanks in advance

Json1:

```
[ 
 {"KEY": "a1 ", "VALUE": "Y"},
 {"KEY": "a2 ", "VALUE": "N"},
 {"KEY": "a3 ", "VALUE": "Y"},
]
```

Json2:

```
[ 
 {
  "TYPE" : "B",
  "ID_NO" : "a1",
  "NUM" : "02",
  "TYPE2" : "40",
  "INFO" : "2F2200102382"
  },
 {
  "TYPE" : "C",
  "ID_NO" : "a2",
  "NUM" : "03",
  "TYPE2" : "45",
  "INFO" : "2G2650132382"
 }
]
```

Output:The "VALUE" field of the first json should be added as "FLAG" in the output json

```
[ 
 {
  "TYPE" : "B",
  "ID_NO" : "a1",
  "NUM" : "02",
  "TYPE2" : "40",
  "INFO" : "2F2200102382",
  "FLAG" : "Y"
 },
{
  "TYPE" : "C",
  "ID_NO" : "a2",
  "NUM" : "03",
  "TYPE2" : "45",
  "INFO" : "2G2650132382",
  "FLAG" : "N"
 }
]
```

Comment: are you using python2 or python3 ?

Comment: i am using python3